# Zend2: Loading partials dynamically via ajax (e.g. for tabs)

Tags: ajax, zend-framework2, partials

I have multiple tabs in my page. At the moment all tabs incl. content get rendered when loading the page (so also the content of the tabs which are not active). Rendering takes too much time, so I'd like to load the content dynamically via ajax. All tab contents are loaded via partials in zend. Is there an efficient way to load partials (containing JS) dynamically?

Comment: Yes your ajax call a controller, and your controller load the partial view as pure HTML, then you just show it on your response

Comment: Yes, that's the typical way. The main problem is the javascript connected with each partial. Of course, the dynamically loaded javascript doesn't work. Is there a better solution than searching for script-tags in the html and execute it via eval?

Comment: From my memory there is a trick to make the javascript work. But I don't remember how